Azure Authentication Issues
I attempted to read a SharePoint site using Python by generating an access token via app registration with a secret. I also granted read/write access to the app. However, this approach failed. On the other hand, when I authenticated using delegated permissions, I was able to access the SharePoint site successfully. Why am I unable to access the SharePoint site in the first scenario?
I tried using deligated and i am able to read
but i wanted to integrate the client secrete to avoid login authentication.

Can you also include the code you are using?

What is the scope you are using?


Note that: If you are making use of client credential flow you need to grant the application access to the site in XML request.

Grant Sites.Selected application type API permission:

Navigate to https://TenantDomain.sharepoint.com/sites/SiteName/_layouts/15/appinv.aspx and create:
<AppPermissionRequests AllowAppOnlyPolicy="true">
    <AppPermissionRequest Scope="http://sharepoint/content/sitecollection" Right="FullControl" />
</AppPermissionRequests>



Use the below code to access SharePoint site:
from azure.identity import ClientSecretCredential
import requests

client_id = 'ClientID'
client_secret = 'Secret'
tenant_id = 'TenantID'
scope = ['https://graph.microsoft.com/.default']

credential = ClientSecretCredential(
    tenant_id=tenant_id,
    client_id=client_id,
    client_secret=client_secret
)

token = credential.get_token(*scope)
access_token = token.token

url = 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/Tenant.sharepoint.com:/sites/SiteName:/'

headers = {
    'Authorization': f'Bearer {access_token}',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
}

response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)

if response.status_code == 200:
    print(response.json())  
else:
    print(f"Error {response.status_code}: {response.text}")


Otherwise assign the App to the selected SharePoint Site by using PnP PowerShell refer this blog by Sang Huynh.
